# A finite group such that every element is conjugate to its square is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite group such that $g$ is conjugate to $g^2$ for every $g\in G$.

Here's a proof that $G$ is trivial.  First, observe that if $\lvert G\rvert$ is even, then $G$ contains an element $h$ of order $2$, in which case, $h$ is conjugate to $h^2=1$.  But this implies that $h=1$, so $h$ does not have order $2$.  By contradiction, $\lvert G\rvert$ is odd.  Then, by the Feit–Thompson theorem, $G$ is solvable.  In particular, this means that the derived series of $G$ terminates.  However, for any $g$ in $G$, there exists $a\in G$ such that $g^2=aga^{-1}$, i.e., $g=aga^{-1}g^{-1}\in G^{(1)}$.  It follows that $G^{(1)}=G$.  In fact, this shows that $G^{(n)}=G$ for all $n\geq 1$.  Since the derived series of $G$ terminates, this implies that $G$ must be trivial.

While I'm convinced of the result, this proof is not particularly satisfying to me, since it relies on Feit-Thompson.  Is there an elementary proof that $G$ is trivial?

Comment: This is a surprisingly hard question (althoughI know very little about finite group theory!)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As you say, $G$ must have odd order. Let $p$ be the smallest prime factor
of the order of $G$, and $a$ an element of order $p$. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $a$, $C$ be the centraliser of $H$ and $N$ the normaliser of $H$. Then
$r=|N:C|$ is the number of elements of $H$ which are conjugates of $a$. So
$r<p$ but $r>1$, as $a^2\ne a$ is the conjugate of $a$. But $r\mid |G|$
and $1<r<p$, contradicting $p$ being the smallest (prime) factor of $|G|$.

Comment: Sorry, why is $r$ the number of elements which are conjugates of $a$?

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to Lord Shark's answer, if you are curious, see Lemma 5.1 of the paper Gabriel Navarro, [*The McKay conjecture and Galois automorphisms*](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v160-n3-p07.pdf), Annals of Mathematics, **160** (2004), 1129–1140.

Comment: Very nice little gem.